# Equal or approximation after initial approximation sign

Tags: notation

I'm wondering what notation of the following two is preferred:

**A)** $\frac{1}{3}+0.7 \approx 0.3 + 0.7 = 1.0$

**B)** $\frac{1}{3}+0.7 \approx 0.3 + 0.7 \approx 1.0$

I guess it depends on if you interpret it as:

$\frac{1}{3}+0.7 $ which is approximately $0.3 + 0.7$ which is exactly equal to $1.0$

*or*

$\frac{1}{3}+0.7 $ which is approximately $0.3 + 0.7$ which is approximately  equal to $1.0$ because of the previous approximation. I would argue for the first.

Answer (score 1):

Since the scope of relations such as equalities and approximations is only the left and the right hand sides, I believe **A)** is preferred.

Comment: I agree. That's what we were always taught too

Answer (score 0):

Consider this (valid) expression:

$$\frac{1}{3} + 0.7 \geq 0.3 + 0.7 = 1.0$$

However you would only see

$$\frac{1}{3} + 0.7 \geq 0.3 + 0.7 \geq 1.0$$

In rare cases. So in general you should use the more exact comparison. Here **A)**